# Evaluate hang the computer to plot a graph with various plots

Tags: plotting

I have this function

```
f[n_, p_] := Probability[x > z, {x, y, z} \[Distributed]
MultinomialDistribution[n, {p, 1 - p - 0.1, 0.1}]]
```

And I want to plot various graphs that depends on `p`, then I had written:

```
DiscretePlot[Table[f[n, p], {p, {0.5, 0.4, 0.3}}], {n, 1, 10}]
```

As expected the above code plots all the graphs with the same color, so I tried to use the standard way to fix this writing

```
DiscretePlot[Evaluate@Table[f[n, p], {p, {0.5, 0.4, 0.3}}], {n, 1, 10}]
```

However with this last code my computer hang on. There is a way to accomplish the task easily, that is, to plot these different graphs together with different colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expr = Table[Table[f[n, p], {p, {0.5, 0.4, 0.3}}], {n, 1, 10}];
ListPlot[Transpose@expr, Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]

Comment: More succinctly, `expr = Table[f[n, p], {p, {.5, .4, .3}}, {n, 10}]; ListPlot[expr, 
 Filling -> Bottom]`